# How to keep authorized_keys in a custom folder

Tags: windows, ssh

I would like to keep authorized_keys of OpenSSH for Windows in a custom folder and not in a C:\Users\SomeUserName folder.

Is it possible?

The manual page does not help http://www.openssh.com/manual.html

Answer (score 1):

From [the manual](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5):

> AuthorizedKeysFile Specifies the file that contains the public keys
>   that can be used for user authentication. The format is described in
>   the AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT section of sshd(8). AuthorizedKeysFile
>   may contain tokens of the form %T which are substituted during
>   connection setup. The following tokens are defined: %% is replaced by
>   a literal '%', %h is replaced by the home directory of the user being
>   authenticated, and %u is replaced by the username of that user. After
>   expansion, AuthorizedKeysFile is taken to be an absolute path or one
>   relative to the user's home directory. Multiple files may be listed,
>   separated by whitespace. Alternately this option may be set to “none”
>   to skip checking for user keys in files. The default is
>   “.ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2”.

Comment: I just checked with option `NONE` but it doesnt work. Is it possible to disable it and use some global folder or even load keys when service starts?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve here. Disabling key auth doesn't seem like a great thing to do.

Comment: By some reason MS Windows has special changes so it changes predefined username to another one but does not create for him folder or even use  the folder of changed username, So the normal way to use C:\Users\SomeUSername\authorized_keys  is impossible. And I want to use like a global loading of keys for all users.